# Remove wp_admin_bar fail on wordpress 4.0

Tags: php

The following code is out of date, can anyone help me update this code?

```
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
  remove_action( 'init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `show_admin_bar(false);` for disabling admin bar
to disable admin bar for all except admin add this to functions.php

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
  show_admin_bar(false);
}
}
```

you can refer about that [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar)